# More generic Content Scripts match pattern?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to match:

```
http://images.orkut.com/
http://www.orkut.co.uk/
http://www.orkut.com.br/
http://images.orkut.jp/
```

The pattern I am trying to use is:

```
http://*.orkut.*/*
```

But when I try to load the extension it says:

```
invalid value for content_scripts[0].matches[0]
```

Is there a way to match these urls without specifying the full domain?

---

In the manifest file

```
"permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*.orkut.*/*", "https://*.orkut.*/*" ],
"content_scripts":
[
    {
        "matches": [ "http://*.orkut.*/" ], // error
        "js": ["content/loader.js"]
    }
]
```

A more generic doesn't work, while this one works:

```
"matches": [ "http://*.orkut.co.uk/" ],
```

Comment: Can you add more context where you define the pattern?

Comment: @marcog I guess that would be misleading. The problem is that chrome doesn't accept this pattern. If it is relevant I am using Chrome 9.0.597.19 beta.

Comment: The reason I ask is that it works for me in Vimiums excluded URLs, which I believe it passes onto Chrome without modification. So there's possibly something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @marcog: Maybe then the newer version doesn't accept this? I guess I will have to allow all URLs and make the filter myself...

Comment: Or perhaps the beta is buggy? Have you tried on the latest stable release? I'm on Chromium 7.0.517.41.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that do to security reasons, please refer to http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html for more information.

As well, team lead of Chrome Extension did a nice explanation why:
http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/msg/3d305eb340f01763

Answer (score 0):

As [Mohamed Mansour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532584/3191896) mentioned, **this is not supported by google** in the `manifest.json`

#### However, you can still add a simple javascript check in your content script!

For example, this is how I workaround a similar case where I wanted the content script to be executed only on `192.168.*.*` hosts (it's an in-house chrome extension)

1. in your **manifest.json** use `<all_urls>`

   ```
   ...
     "content_scripts": [
       {
         "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
         "js": ["content-script.js"]
       }
     ],
   ...
   ```
2. in your **content-script.js** use a simple condition to verify if the hostname matches a regex pattern

   ```
   let isValidHostname = /^192.168.\d+.\d+$/.test(window.location.hostname);
   if (isValidHostname){
       // Do your stuff here
   }
   ```